# Create custom TextMate command to compile *.coffee into *.js

Tags: coffeescript, textmate

How to create custom TextMate command to compile *.coffee into *.js? I wanna edit my *.coffee file, then hit shortcut (something like cmd-shift-B) and get my new *.js file, in same folder as my *.coffee file.

I can achieve same effect in bash via simple command:

```
$ coffee -cb
```

But can't understand, how do this via TextMate's commands. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do this yourself. It has already been done. See this [bundle](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script-tmbundle) for TextMate.

It adds the command `Cmd+B` for building and displaying the CoffeeScript file.

*Update*

if you take a look at [this file](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script-tmbundle/blob/master/Commands/Compile%20and%20Display%20JS.tmCommand) you can see that the command is just a shell script which you can easily manipulate to compile the content into a file.

Comment: Unfortunately, this bundle only displaying compiled code, it doesn't creating *.js file.